# How do I get Cucumber HTML Reporter to generate a new report on command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am running tests using CucmberJS and SeleniumWebdriver on Node.js.

I have installed the package [cucumber-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-html-reporter). This is somewhat working, but for a few things:

1. The report.html file does not update when a test is run. I must manually delete the file each time.
2. The report.html file opens itself *before* a test is run, giving information of the prior test, not the current test.

My index.js file is as such:

```
var reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');

var options = {
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        jsonFile: 'reports/report.json',
        output: 'reports/report.html',
        reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
        scenarioTimestamp: true,
        launchReport: true,
        metadata: {
            "Test Environment": "Prod",
            "Browser": "Firefox 109.0.1",
            "Platform": "MacOS 12.4",
            "Parallel": "Scenarios",
            "Executed": "Local"
        },
        failedSummaryReport: true,
    };
reporter.generate(options);
```

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?